# Effects if i don't update my Node.js

Tags: node.js

I haven't updated my Node for a very long time. My current version is v.6.12.3

Would there be any bugs if I don't update my Node?

Comment: you will miss the new features of ES6/7 if you don't update and some minor bugs

Comment: Until recently, I've run Node 6 locally with no issues. Of course, you won't be able to use ES2017+ features in your own code without a transpiler. Almost every third-party package still supports it. The only exception I've seen was https://github.com/bencevans/node-sonos , it's restricted to 0.x version for Node 6.

Comment: I have a local project which I started off in Nodev6 and it still is based on v6. However, my gitlab runner will use node:latest and update all of my packages. And gues what - it's even still running on the same code-base without any errors. Maybe that would also be a good approach for you, so you can always be sure that you >could< update without any problems whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Node 6 has [long-term support state until April, 2019](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule).

Node 6.12 is quite stable and has [99% support for ES6](https://node.green/), it's acceptable to use it for development. It's recommended to update to latest Node 6 release for security and bug fixes, especially in production.

It's possible that some packages use features that aren't supported by Node 6 or mark it as unsupported in package.json `engines`, but in fact almost every third-party package still supports it.